# Posting form without a name using Mechanize

Tags: perl

I'm pulling a webpage which contains stats for ball players.  The page is page 1 of several pages.  There is also a dropdown to allow viewing more than 30 players at a time, allowing 500 so I can see all of them on one page.  I'm not sure how to pull the page with all 500 players, so I pull the main page and then there is a form to post with a pagesize of 500.  The problem is that the form doesn't have a name, only an id.  And when I attempt to post the form with "id = form1" it says it doesn't exist.  I did a data dumper and here is the post.  I would use wget or curl but it doesn't allow me to pull the file with PageSize=500, as it only defaults to 30.  And the other issue is the get object and the post object.  Will I need to create a cookie jar, or does the agent_alias take care of that.

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'default_charset' => 'UTF-8',
                 'enctype' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'accept_charset' => 'UNKNOWN',
                 'action' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0&PageSize=500')}, 'URI::https' ),
                 'method' => 'POST',
                 'attr' => {
                             'id' => 'form1',
                             'method' => 'post'
                           },
                 'inputs' => [
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        '/' => '/',
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '',
                                        'name' => 'RadScriptManager1_TSM',
                                        'id' => 'RadScriptManager1_TSM',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        '/' => '/',
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '/wEPDwUJNTA2ODMzMzI3D2QWBAIBD2QWAgIBDxYCHgRUZXh0BegBPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0nZGVzY3JpcHRpb24nIGNvbnRlbnQ9J1N0ZWFtZXIgYmFzZWJhbGwgcHJvamVjdGlvbnMgZm9yIGJhdHRlcnMgYW5kIHRoZSAyMDIwIHNlYXNvbicgLz4NCjxtZXRhIG5hbWU9J2tleXdvcmRzJyBjb250ZW50PSdiYXNlYmFsbCBwcm9qZWN0aW9ucywgYmF0dGVyIHByb2plY3Rpb25zLCBzdGVhbWVyI
```

There are several other inputs listed but not sure if I will need those.  I can post the whole thing if needed.  Here is the small snippet of code that I'm running.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias('Linux Mozilla');
my $url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0&PageSize=500";
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    id => 'form1',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `form_id` parameter in `submit_form` call (instead of **wrong** `id`).

```
$mech->submit_form(
  form_id => 'form1',
);
```

[man WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize)

> **mech->submit_form( ... )**
>   …
>   • "form_id => ID"
>   Selects the form with ID ID (calls "form_id()")

Comment: Appreciate the responses, but even using the form_id only results in the same page being returned, which is 30 players listed.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter is [form_id](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#$mech-%3Eform_id(-$name-)), not just `id`.